# Access a nested element using NSIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsarray, nsindexpath

Is there really no API for using `NSIndexPath` to traverse/access a nested array construct in the iOS SDK? I've looked in the docs for both `NSIndexPath` and `NSArray`?

For example:

```
NSArray *nested = @[
    @[
        @[@1, @2], @[@10, @20]
    ],
    @[
        @[@11, @22], @[@110, @220]
    ],
    @[
        @[@111, @222], @[@1110, @2220]
    ]
];
```

If I wanted to model the access path to @222, I could assemble:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [[[NSIndexPatch indexPathWithIndex: 2] indexPathByAddingIndex: 0] indexPathByAddingIndex: 1];
```

So do I have to write my own recursive accessor?

```
id probe = nested;
for (NSInteger position = 0; position < path.length; position++) {
    probe = probe[path indexAtPosition: position];
}
```

It would amaze me that Apple went this far to actually model the construct, but then not provide an API to bridge the two together. I would expect a method on either `NSArray` or `NSIndexPath` which allowed one to do something like:

```
id value = [nested objectAtIndexPath: path];
```

Or maybe there's a more idiomatic twist I'm missing?

---

## UPDATE:

I chose to follow the advice of @CrimsonChris and put together the following:

### NSArray+NestedAccess.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSObject (NestedAccess)
- (id) objectAtPath: (NSIndexPath*) path;
@end
```

### NSArray+NestedAccess.c

```
#import "NSArray+NestedAccess.h"
@implementation NSArray (NestedAccess)
- (id) objectAtPath: (NSIndexPath*) path {
    id probe = self;
    for (NSInteger position = 0; position < path.length; position++) {
        probe = ((NSArray*)probe)[path indexAtPosition: position];
    }
    return probe;
}
@end
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking.  Looking for `getIndexes:`?  `indexPathWithIndexes:length:`? `indexAtPosition`?

Comment: if you aren't afraid of swizelling, you can do much more: http://kickingbear.com/blog/archives/9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a category for NSIndexPath! NSIndexPath is not designed to "just work" with NSArrays. It is generic enough to be used in multiple kinds of data structures.

Comment: Wish there was an example of doing that. I've not experienced authoring my own category/extensions yet. If there was, I'd give this one the answer.

Comment: Apple provides categories for `NSIndexPath` for use in UITableViews and UICollectionViews. That's where `row`, `section`, and `item` come from.

Answer (score 0):

Just use indexing:

```
NSLog (@"nested 222: %@", nested[2][0][1]);
```

NSLog output:

> nested 222: 222

But perhaps I don't understand what you mean by:

> If I wanted to model the access path to @222, I could assemble:

If you want to use `NSIndexPath` why not create a subclass that performs array indexing. Or create a helper class or method.